# Converting nested python lists to database

Tags: python, database, list, dictionary, nested

I have a python list that has a structure like this:

```
apts = [ [2083, \
           [ ["price", "$1000 / month"], \
             ["sq ft.", "500"], \
             ["amenities", "gym hardwood floor"]]], \
          [1096, \ 
           [ ["price", "$1200 / month"], \
             ["sq ft.", "700"], \
             ["a/c", "true"]]], \
          [76, \ 
           [ ["price", "$1100 / month"], \
             ["Pets", "true"], \
             ["a/c", "true"]]]]
```

how do I get it in a format such that I can easily transfer it to a mysql database? Basically, I want to rearrange this in such a way that it resembles a table/csv file that would be easily transferable, like:

```
id, price, sq ft, amenities, a/c, pets
2083, $1000 / month, 500, gym hardwood floor, ,
1096, $1200 / month, 700, , true,
76, $1100 / month, , true, true
```

Thanks in advance. I can think of ways in which I map these piece by piece, but it's seems pretty inefficient, and my knowledge of python is weak, so I'm hoping there are other quick methods for converting this data...

Would it be helpful if instead of a nested list I used a nested dictionary structure?

Comment: Is there a reason this is a list? It looks like it should be a dict to me.

Comment: I just haven't really learned enough about python, but yes, I should definitely be using dictionaries for this application. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is that your difficulty is in converting your complex structure into strings of values. Here is how it could be done:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

out = []

for r in apts:
    row = OrderedDict([('id',''), ('price',''), ('sqft',''), 
                       ('amenities',''),('ac',''),('pets','')])        
    row['id']=r[0]
    for sr in r[1]:
        row[sr[0].lower().translate(None," ./")]=sr[1]
    out.append(row)

#print result        
for o in out:
    s = ",".join(map(str, o.values()))
    print s
```

prints

```
2083,$1000 / month,500,gym hardwood floor,,
1096,$1200 / month,700,,true,
76,$1100 / month,,,true,true
```

Comment: Thanks! this is definitely what I was looking for - what is the value of using the translate function in this case?

Answer (score 1):

I may have misunderstood the question, but to output your list as a csv you would:

```
import csv

out_file = open('/path/to/out_file.csv', 'wb')
writer = csv.writer(out_file, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
for data_row in apts:
    writer.writerow(data_row)
```

To import into SQL (assuming that your list is ordered correctly and you have properly escaped your data)

```
import MySQLdb
mysql = MySQLdb.connect(host=host, user=user,passwd=passwd,db=db)
cursor = self.mysql.cursor()
queries = []
for row in apts:
    queries.append("('%s')" % "','".join(row) ) #< this will join the data encapsuled in apostrophes
cursor.execute( "INSERT INTO TABLE VALUES %s" % ",".join(queries) ) #< Insert the data
```

I would definitely recommend using a dictionary if you are dumping this to a database so that you are 100% that the data is going to the right place.